# NEAR Protocol Smart Contract Instantiation Error

Tags: nearprotocol, near

I am trying to deploy the smart contract for a NEAR Protocol DAO. I am facing a problem during the Instantiation of the contract.

I am passing this data to create a DAO but it is not working -
[image: Transaction Data Snapshot]
Link to the above transaction - https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/8z1utD7PnhD7y1PN9uuTD4Lf3rbooQ5kvsh92U1TaYvF

This is what the error message looks like:
*Failure:*

```json
{
  "ActionError": {
    "index": 3,
    "kind": {
      "FunctionCallError": {
        "CompilationError": {
          "PrepareError": "Instantiate"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the function signature to instantiate the new DAO:
[image: Function signature]

It would be great if someone can help me out. Even a pointer to the solution would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and In my case that was because I used chrono lib. I removed the library and it worked. The error could be some where else not just in the init function